# Parola per indicare una persona che si offende per niente?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives, vocabulary

Ragazzi/e, ho un vuoto di memoria: che parola si usa per indicare una persona che si offende per frasi/atteggiamenti a cui nessun altro farebbe caso?

Comment: In genovese potrebbe essere *patiscimile*.

Comment: @Edo Ho convertito la tua risposta in commento, il che non toglie valore; solo che non era adeguata agli standard del sito, che è sulla lingua italiana. Sei ugualmente il benvenuto, aspettiamo altri contributi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come non detto, mi è venuto in mente: [permaloso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/permaloso/).

Dal vocabolario Treccani:

> permalóso agg. – Detto di persona facile a offendersi, che, per
>   eccessivo amor proprio, si risente e s’indispettisce di atti e parole
>   che altri non considererebbero offensivi (e che per lo più non sono
>   tali nelle intenzioni)

Comment: Anche *suscettibile*, forse

Comment: @egreg Sì, anche _suscettibile_!

Comment: Mi sembra una domanda da "Settimana Enigmistica". È utile per questo sito?

Comment: @Gio Non mi toccare "La Settimana Enigmistica"! Visto che l'hanno votata in sei, direi di sì... e poi a furia di essere fiscali non usciremo mai dal "beta" (v. https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1301/2609).

Comment: Che parola posso usare per dire "parlare ad alta voce"? o "camminare velocemente"? Non so, mi sembrano domande un po' da quiz, accettabili forse da uno straniero, comunque sono previste dal regolamento, per cui...

Comment: @Gio Un italiano non può dimenticarsi una parola? Anche su altri siti linguistici ci sono domande del genere, non mi sembra poi così inutile...

Comment: È la risposta che è stata votata da sei persone, non la domanda...

Comment: @DaG Comunque mi sembrate troppo pignoli, v. il post di andy256 sul meta-sito...

Comment: @DaG Ad esempio: ho avuto un downvote anche sulla risposta, ovviamente senza un commento che ne spiegasse la motivazione. Posso capirlo sulla domanda ma la risposta cos'ha di sbagliato? Per me l'etichetta di questo sito va rivista.

Comment: Su questo sono d'accordo con te, @CarLaTeX.

Comment: Anch'io sono d'accordo con te, @CarLaTeX: ultimamente anch'io ho stato ricevendo parecchi voti negativi senza nessuna spiegazione.

Answer (score 1):

*Permaloso* è la parola corretta, ma parlando puoi anche usare [*malmostoso*](https://unaparolaalgiorno.it/significato/M/malmostoso).